# Filter out resources from custom Test task in Gradle with goal of having one properties file for tests and a different one for production

Tags: gradle

So I have setup a way to just run integration tests using this configuration:

```
test {
    exclude "**/*IntegrationTest*.class"
}

task integrationTest(type: Test, dependsOn: testClasses) {
    include "**/*IntegrationTest*.class"
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest
```

Works great.  But then for logging in my integration tests, I want to use a log4j.properties file from a specific directory instead of the one that is located in the `src/main/resoures` which is used for production.

I've tried this but didn't work:

```
  integrationTest.classpath = files("$rootDir/test/src/main/resources/log4j.properties") + integrationTest.classpath
```

I also tried to just see if I could exclude the file, but could not find a way.  Tried this:

```
  processTestResources.exclude "**/*log4j.properties"
```

Any suggestions for including one properties file in production and another one for tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the 'test' log4j.properties in the `src/test/resources` directory, it will actually come before anything in `src/main/resources` on the classpath of your tests/integration tests.

An alternative solution is to setup your bundling so that the log4j.properties for production is not in src/main/resources, but is added to the jar from a different directory...

```
jar {
  from('production') {
    include('log4j.properties')
  }
}
```

If you want to keep the `log4j.properties` files in their current locations, you were almost there with what you tried. On the classpath you can have either jar files, or directories containing resources. So try doing this:

```
integrationTest.classpath = files("$rootDir/test/src/main/resources") + integrationTest.classpath
```

Comment: The first suggestion works.  But I'd like to keep the log4j.properties where it is.  So I tried manually adding it to the test resources this way `sourceSets.test.resources.srcDir files("$rootDir/test/src/main/resources/log4j.properties")` which didn't work.  Any ideas why adding it programmatically didn't work?

Comment: Yeah, I tried exactly what you listed before...manipulating the integrationTest classpath.  Didn't work to my surprise.  I've decided a better idea is to explicitly add it to production from a different directory like you listed first.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could do something like this also so that the .jar task will include it later:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'src/main/java'
      output.classesDir   = 'build/classes/main'      
    }
    resources {
      srcDir 'src/main/resources'
      include 'logback.xml'
      output.resourcesDir = 'build/resources/main'
    }
  }
}
```